# How to compare Specific value of two different tables in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two tables 'Contact' and other is "Subscriber".. I want to Compare Contact_id of both and want to  show only those Contact_id which is present in Contact but not in Subscriber.These two tables are in two different Models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Contact.objects.exclude(
    id__in=Subscriber.objects.all()
).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Note that these are actually two SQL queries. I'm sure there are ways to optimize it, but this will usually work fine.

Also, the `values_list` has nothing to do with selecting the objects, it just modifies "format" of what is returned (list of IDs instead of queryset of objects - but same database records in both cases).

If you are excluding by some field other then `Subscriber.id` (e.g: `Subscriber.quasy_id`):

```
Contact.objects.exclude(
    id__in=Subscriber.objects.all().values_list('quasy_id', flat=True)
).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

**Edit:**

This answer assumes you don't have a relationship between your `Contact` and `Subscriber` models. If you do, then see @navit's answer, it is a better choice.

**Edit 2:**

That `flat=True` inside `exclude` is actually not needed.

Comment: Yes there is no relationship between Contact and Subscriber

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your model like this:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

You can do what you want like this:

```
my_list = Subscriber.objects.filter(contact=None)
```

This retrieves Subscribers which don't have a Contact. Retrieveing a list of Contacts is straightforward.

Comment: Works for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare value of fields in two different tables(which have connection with ForeignKey) you can use something like this:

I assume model is like below:

```
class Contact(models.Model):  
 name = models.TextField()
 family = models.TextField()

class Subscriber(models.Model):
 subscriber_name = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 subscriber_family = models.TextField()
```

this would be the query:

```
query = Subscriber.objects.filter(subscriber_name =F(Contact__name))
return query
```